# Universal language for writing GUI (C++)

Tags: c++, user-interface

Consider task: programmer must write the same GUI dialog on C++ with the help of two different frameworks (e.g. C++ Builder and Qt).

Has he to rewrite all calls, for example, to fill combobox? Is there any metalanguage to describe elements of user interface?

Comment: QML is the tool you are looking for i think :)

Comment: @DanielSanchez it's a very good suggestion) but I have to build one version exactly with C++ Builder GUI classes :(

Comment: You mean then that you want a metalenguage to comunicate qt with c++builder?

Comment: @DanielSanchez Ideally I want write one text to compile it without changes in C++ Builder and in Qt Creator (as an IDE for Qt)

Comment: never used c++ builder so actually im lost on this topic far from qt , sorry

Comment: @DanielSanchez u may consider any other framework for building user interfaces different from Qt - question stays the same

Comment: I dont think you are gonna find anything like you are expecting :/

Comment: Why would you do this?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath because I have to use one framework for Windows and another framework for Linux.

Comment: I second Karoly Horvath. The frameworks already cover platform specific issues. Choose one and stick with it.

Comment: @Sas Well, that is why people use a cross platform library/framework(such as Qt) - so they do not have to write their application several times, for each platform. However, a universal language that you ask about does not currently exist.

Answer (score 0):

Nope,

C++ Builder:

```
TLabel* label = new TLabel(NULL);
label->Text = "Hallo";
```

Qt:

```
QLabel* label = new QLabel(NULL);
label->setText("Hallo");
```

You can write something yourself, but as you can see, those two worlds does not mix.

*Move to Qt completely, that is what I did*

Comment: You can always subclass all GUI elements in C++ Builder to wrap their properties in getter and setter functions... Trying to wrap the Qt classes will probably never work.

Comment: An option would be the Firemonkey framework in C++ Builder as well, but last time I checked Firemonkey was not supported for Linux, only Mac OS (Checked few years ago just before the move to Qt)